# Redirect to other pages not working after logging into Custom CMS using PHP

Tags: php, session, redirect, authentication, content-management-system

I'm making a custom Content Management System for a website I built, and so far everything is looking good up until this road block. I got my code to work to where from login.php page you can enter in the username and password and it successfully redirects me to the index.php page but then I decided that I need to redirect anyone who isn't logged in to login.php before looking at other pages on my CMS.

So in comes this code right here...

```
<?php require_once("lib/sessions.php");
      require_once("lib/functions.php");
      require_once("meta.php");
      login_confirm(); 
?>
```

That is at the top of each page in my CMS and that login_confirm function looks like this...

```
function login_confirm() {
    if(!logged_in()) {
        redirect_to("login.php");
    }
}

function logged_in() {
    return isset($_SESSION['admin_id']);
}
```

The $_SESSION['admin_id'] gets set on my login page like this...

```
$found_admin = attempt_login($username, $password); 
    if($found_admin) {
        //Success, mark user as logged in
        $_SESSION["admin_id"] = $found_admin["id"];
        $_SESSION["username"] = $found_admin["username"];
        redirect_to("index.php"); 
    } else {
        //failed
        $_SESSION["message"] = "Log in failed"; 
    }
```

And like I said in the beginning, the login page will successfully redirect you to index.php no problem, but that was before I put login_confirm() at the top of my pages. Now no matter what I always get redirected to login.php even though I typed in the right credentials. I assume the Session isn't saving or something...

Edits: session.php looks like this. So the session is being started at the top of the page.

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
ob_start();
//function for message and errors
?>
```

Comment: `require_once("lib/sessions.php);` First line first error. Also do i have to ask if you have `session_start();` in ever file you use : `$_SESSION` ?

Comment: That was just an error in my typing in the code here. I fixed it here and the session.php is in the edits

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that You are using session_start(); Before using $_SESSION You must initialize it.

Comment: I do initialize it in lib/session.php